# Very basic javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have been doing leaflet API since 2 days. I have been stuck in a function call which gives me unexpected behaviour. the code is as follows

```
var it=0;
 
var map = L.map('map1', {
    center:[51.505,-0.09],
    zoom: 2,
});
 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/c77b2fb7bfb74f74998061abda20d58f/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
    attribution: '2013 &copy @ Rajat/Akshat',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
 
var marker = L.marker([51.5,-0.09], {draggable: true, opacity: 0.8}).addTo(map);

function onDragEnd(e) {
    var lat_marker = e.target._latlng.lat;
    var lng_marker = e.target._latlng.lng;      
}

var i=6;
marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd(event));
```

The map1 `div` id has been created on HTML page.

Now the problem is this function:

```
marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd(event));
```

It shows this error

> ReferenceError: event is not defined
>
> marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd(event));

But when I pass it without any argument `marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd());`, it works.

Also, I want to add my own parameter in the function:

```
marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd(i));
```

Where `i` is some simple variable. But something is wrong in this function, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Sometimes just indenting the code properly can make spotting mistakes easier...

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 4):

```
onDragEnd(event)
```

executes the function. You just need to pass in the function reference

```
marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd);
```

Using **()** after the function executes the function immediately. You want this method to act as a callback when the drag ends.

And event object is passed in y default, when this method is invoked. So you need not worry about passing it as an argument

```
function onDragEnd(event) {
```

To pass in the custom parameter you can try something in these lines..

```
for(var i=0; i < $('span').length ; i++) {
    $('span').eq(i).on('click', bindClick(i));
}

function bindClick(index) {
    return function(e) {
        dragEnd(e, index);
    }
}

function dragEnd(e, index) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(index);
}
```

**Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.marker').length; i++) {
    var marker = $('.marker').eq(i);
    $('span').eq(i).on('dragend', bindDragEnd(i));
}

function bindDragEnd(index) {
    return function (e) {
        dragEnd(e, index);
    }
}

function dragEnd(e, index) {
    console.log(e);
    // you can access the marker object 
    //by accessing it like $('.marker').eq(index)
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/udcQ9/)**

Comment: The event object is passed in by default in every browser except Firefox (Gecko), I believe.

Comment: thanks @sushanth . can you please tell me how can i customize this event. Like when this event handler function is executed, it contains a variable which i can manipulate. example

myarray[i].on('dragend',onDragEnd); ...i want to access i inside this event handler function....thanks

Comment: @rink.attendant.6.. Right..  But jQuery library takes care of passing a factory library object that encases the event by default even in firefox. So it should not be a problem

Comment: how would i pass an calling object in event handler function ? please reply