# Basic JavaScript concept of event handler

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I want to access the object which called the event handler in event handler function.

For example:

```
marker.on('dragend',onDragEnd);
```

here `marker` is object which on `Dragend` event calls `ondragEnd` function.

`onDragEnd` function is defined like this:

```
function onDragEnd(e) {
                
         var lat_marker = e.target._latlng.lat;
         var lng_marker = e.target._latlng.lng;
        //how can i get marker object here
        //thank you for help
}
```

now can I access marker inside `onDragEnd` function anyhow?

Comment: You have already asked the question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386758/very-basic-javascript-function-call/18386775#18386775

Comment: You mean using `this`?

Comment: Try `marker`? *Where* is `onDragEnd` defined?

Comment: @Sushanth--it works ..thanks..i didn't see your code earlier

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could access to marker by using the keyword `this`.
Your code would be like this (I didn't try it but it should work):

```
function onDragEnd(e) {
    var lat_marker = e.target._latlng.lat;
    var lng_marker = e.target._latlng.lng;
    // accessing marker object (raw)
    var markerRaw = this;
    // accessing marker as a jQuery object
    var markerJquery = $(markerRaw);
}
```